# finding a specific value in a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

Is there a code for finding a specific value in a hashmap?
I want to use a for loop to convert values in a hashmap into an int.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < items; i++) {
        cost = Integer.parseInt(myHashmap);
    }
```

can I even use .parseInt on a hashmap or is there another way to convert a place in a hashmap into a int?
Like `String[3]` is there a code to find a specific place in a hashmap?

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean "find a specific key / value pair" or "find a specific value".  You would use the Map get method to get a value for a particular key.  If you're just looking for a particular value, you can use the Map values method.

Comment: Instead of asking such a basic question, you should go through the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). If you are stuck somewhere, you should describe your question well e.g. mention a sample input & expected behaviour and output etc.

Comment: How do "find a specific value in a map" and "i want to use a loop to convert all values" go together? Which is it, a specific value or all values?

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over all values of a map, use the `values` method:

```
Map<Long, String> map = ...;
for (final String value = map.values()) {
  System.out.println(value);
}
```

To find a specific value, iterate all values, check against your predicate and return if found:

```
String findValue(final Map<Long, String> map, final Predicate<String> condition) {
  for (final String value = map.values()) {
    if (condition.test(value)) {
      return value;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

To find the key for a given value, iterate the *entry set* of the map:

```
Long findKey(final Map<Long, String> map, final String value) {
  for (final Map.Entry<Long, String> entry = map.entrySet()) {
    if (Objects.equals(entry.getValue(), value)) {
      return entry.getKey();
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Of course, once you have a value (or a key), you can use it any way you like. That includes passing it as argument to `Integer.parseInt`.

Answer (score -1):

`myHashmap.values()` will return all the values of the `Map`. `Integer.parseInt(value)` parses the String argument as a signed decimal integer object.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> myHashmap = new HashMap<>();
        myHashmap.put("A", "10");
        myHashmap.put("B", "20");
        myHashmap.put("C", "30");
        myHashmap.values().forEach(value -> {
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(value));
            // Rest of the logic
        });
    }
```